# Проблема с созданием списков xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Как сделать список на подобие listview, но только чтобы элементы этого списка можно было открывать в полноэкранном режиме с прокруткой, сколько не капаюсь на сайтах с руководствами, нигде найти информацию по этому поводу не могу, помогите, пожалуйста.
Пример того что я хочу на скриншотах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/4.8.php

Comment: по ссылке же listview только небольшое окно открывает

Comment: Сделали вывод не читая и не разбираясь. По клику делать можно что угодно.